# Помогите с Select top, distinct, newid()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не могу навертеть запрос, чтобы получить 100 случайных записей с разными товарами.

Таблица:

```
statid int,
billid int,
createdate date
```

`statid` - первичный ключ
`billid` - повторяется

Нужны 100 случайных записей, чтобы `billid` был разный.

Comment: Идеологически `WHERE 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY billid ORDER BY RAND())`. Синтаксически - оконная функция в CTE, отбор в запросе.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, все получилось